# Autohotkey extract text using regex

Tags: regex, string, variables, match, autohotkey

I am just now learning regex using autohotkey but can't figure out how to extract specific string and save to a variable?

Line of text I am searching:
    T   NW CO NORWALK HUB   NW 201-DS3-WLFRCTAICM5-NRWLCT02K16 [DS3 LEC]    -1  -1  PSTN

I am trying to save, **NW 201-DS3-WLFRCTAICM5-NRWLCT02K16 [DS3 LEC]** ONLY.

Here is my regex code: 
NW\D\d.*DS3.*]

But how do I store that as a variable in autohotkey?

I have tried RegexMatch but that only shows the position. I am doing something wrong.

Comment: `RegExMatch(str,"NW\D\d.*DS3.*\]",matches)`, then `matches[0]` will contain the match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may provide the third argument that will hold the match array:

```
RegExMatch(str,"NW\D\d.*DS3.*\]",matches)
```

Then, `matches[0]` will contain the match.

If you use capturing groups inside the pattern, you will be able to access their values by using further indices. If you use `"NW\D(\d.*DS3.*)\]"` against `"NW 5xxx DS3 yyy]`, you will have the whole string inside `matches[0]` and `matches[1]` will hold `5xxx DS3 yyy`.

See AHK `RegExMatch` docs:

> `FoundPos := RegExMatch(Haystack, NeedleRegEx [, UnquotedOutputVar = "", StartingPosition = 1])`
>   
>   UnquotedOutputVar
>   **Mode 1 (default):** *OutputVar* is the unquoted name of a variable in which to store the part of *Haystack* that matched the entire pattern. If the pattern is not found (that is, if the function returns 0), this variable and all array elements below are made blank.
>   
>   If any [capturing subpatterns](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm#subpat) are present inside *NeedleRegEx*, their matches are stored in a [pseudo-array](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Arrays.htm#pseudo) whose base name is *OutputVar*. For example, if the variable's name is *Match*, the substring that matches the first subpattern would be stored in *Match1*, the second would be stored in *Match2*, and so on. The exception to this is [named subpatterns](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExMatch.htm#NamedSubPat): they are stored by name instead of number. For example, the substring that matches the named subpattern `"(?P<Year>\d{4})"` would be stored in *MatchYear*. If a particular subpattern does not match anything (or if the function returns zero), the corresponding variable is made blank.

Comment: Thank you! That makes much more sense the way you explained it.

Answer (score 1):

```
; If you want to delete ALL ....

Only(ByRef C)
{

/*
RegExReplace
https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExReplace.htm
*/

; NW 201-DS3-WLFRCTAICM5-NRWLCT02K16 [DS3 LEC] 

C:=RegExReplace(C, "NW\s[\w-]+\s\[[\w\s]+\]","",ReplacementCount,-1) 

if (ReplacementCount = 0)
return C
else
return Only(C)

} ; Only(ByRef C)

string:="Line of text I am searching: T NW CO NORWALK HUB NW 201-DS3-WLFRCTAICM5-NRWLCT02K16 [DS3 LEC] -1 -1 PSTN"

Result:=Only(string)
MsgBox, % Result
MsgBox, % Only(string)
```